# How should I stop the terrace garden from ruining the terrace

Tags: roof, waterproofing, water-damage, gardening, garden

My terrace is covered with white colour cooling tile to prevent heat from dissipating into the below floor.

I have bought 18 flower pots and vegetable seeds to make the garden.

[image]

I noticed that there's a small hole underneath the pot that means excessive water will drip down to the white cooling tile and make that dirty and also it increases chance of water damage.

My tile is well grouted but I want to be bit more careful when it comes to water damage.

so I'm wondering what are the hacks to stop any water damage by this terrace garden

Comment: "Cost-effective" and yet looking good per OP's comments below are very relative, and opinion-based, therefore unanswerable satisfactorily. Some idea of OP's ideas of what constitutes "cost-effective" in hard currency as well as what OP thinks is nice-looking may make the question more answerable.

Comment: The edit only moved this even _further_ into opinion based territory. What you may consider aesthetically pleasing and cost effective may be a criminal fashion faux pax and outrageously expensive to me. Or, vice-versa.

Comment: TBH, the most "cost effective" (most likely) method of keeping the tile clean is to move the pots when you notice that it's dirty looking and hose it down. Maybe use a little soap and a scrub brush, if necessary, to clean to your desired level of clean.

Comment: @FreeMan - I get it , i have edited my question now. Your approach to the problem is quite intuitive but it's cumbersome. I'd like to know if there are any other ways to deal with the similar scenario

Comment: I wonder if https://gardening.stackexchange.com/ might be a better place for this question? Their "containers" tag seems promising.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [potting trays](https://www.trueleafmarket.com/products/bootstrap-farmer-1020-trays-no-holes). They come in many sizes.

You can also use [plant saucers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08NPHBC6L). (also come in many sizes.)

Comment: Thanks , I have 18 pots .. the terrace is graded towards outlet pipe. Is there any single sheet upon which I can place all 18 pots and dripping water will be led to terrace outlet pipe

Comment: See my answer...."potting trays"

Answer (score 3):

Put the pots on a table or stand with a waterproof channel underneath the stand that will carry the dripping water to a place where it can go safely:

[image: water stand]

The table/stand top should be porous or have holes drilled in it, or made of deck strips, so water can flow through the top to the water channel.

Comment: Or just create the "tabletop" out of two boards, leaving a gap between them above the gutter.  (Might help to angle the boards with a slight slope from the outside edge to the gap.)  Position the pots so the hole is in the gap.

Comment: @Huesmann could you attach a picture please ?

Comment: @Triplefault - seems like an expensive option.the terrace is graded towards outlet pipe. Is there any single sheet upon which I can place all 18 pots and dripping water will be led to terrace outlet pipe

Comment: "Expensive" and "cost-effective" are relative terms. Your green pots themselves might be "expensive" to others. A roll of plastic under the pots and bent up to clip onto the rims of the pots will work to run the water to the drain, and be cheap, but would be ugly as sin. "Is there any single sheet upon which I can..." is leaning towards a shopping search question which may be considered off-topic.

Comment: @Triplefault - Aesthetics is something important too.

Comment: Not a doubt of that, @Vivo. I submit my idea is aesthetically pleasing. But it may be more expensive than your idea of expense can handle.

Comment: @Triplefault - makes sense